# Forcing "Save As" dialog via jQuery GET

Tags: php, jquery, get, savefiledialog

I'm calling a jQuery "GET" on the test.php file code below.

I'm trying to get the script to pop a "Save As" dialog on the resulting test.ini file to allow it to be saved locally. However, although I can echo the result back to the jQuery fine, I can't seem to pop the "save as" dialog.

Update: Thanks to the solutions below, I just changed my $.get to a window.location.replace.

```
$('#test').click(
    function()
    {
        //$.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/test.php');
        window.location.replace("<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/test.php");

    }
);
```

Comment: I believe an AJAX request can never show up the Save As dialog. Why not just navigate to that page instead of an AJAX request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get an ajax request to show a "Save As" dialog, but what you CAN do is insert a hidden iframe element in the page, then set the source of that iframe to the url you want the user to download. Voila, there's your Save As.

Here's a copy and paste example:

```
$('a#linky').click(function(){
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
  iframe.src = 'http://example.com/branding.zip'; 
  iframe.style.display = "none"; 
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: +1 for copy/paste. I ended up just changing my $.get to a window.location.replace but I may do this later.

Comment: not working for me, my pdf show on the iframe but the "save as" dialog never appear :(.. Just testing Using google chrome...

Comment: @nahum Is the PDF being served with a Content-Disposition: attachment header? If not, Chrome will just render it instead of downloading the file.

Comment: For me was easier to open a new blank window and put the 
content-disposition and resolve my problem...

Comment: I realise this is a year old now, but I've been successfully using this code (in the answer) when running the server locally, but when I run the server on a remote machine, the iframe never shows up. In fact, nothing at all happens: the server logs report the file retrieved successfully. But no save-as dialog appears. Could anyone suggest why this might happen?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an AJAX for this.  Just navigate to the php in question and in that php use

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=whatever.dat');
```

This will pop-up the "save as" dialogue box and you'll remain on the original page.

Comment: Works unless the PHP in question errors out, in which case it WILL navigate to the new URL and print the error for the user.  For this reason, I prefer to use a new frame (or, as Jimmy suggests, an iFrame.)

Comment: Well, naturally, if you get errors in the system, then the behaviour will not be the same as you expect.  If you use iframe method suggested by Jimmy and your php errors out, from the user's point of view nothing will happen at all.  That is, the user clicks the button/link/etc - and nothing happens - also not the best user experience.

Comment: Don't you just love the downvotes with no comments - five years after the answer!

Comment: Here's one to make up for it. Congrats on your pending android gold badge.

Answer (score 1):

An AJAX request can't spawn the file download dialog.  Consider instead opening your download target in a new window.