# Javascript Save As dialog only works with localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using the following code to create a save as dialog for a file served statically on the server:

```
open: function() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('dialog-overlay');
},
close: function() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').removeClass('dialog-overlay');
},
buttons: {
    "Save": function() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"); 
    iframe.src = 'static/staticfile.txt'; 
    iframe.style.display = "none"; 
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    return false;
 },
     ...
     ...
```

The iframe functionality reacts to the "Save" button being pressed, which belongs to a jQuery UI menu widget.

This save-as code is based on the accepted answer for this question: [Forcing "Save As" dialog via jQuery GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699461/forcing-save-as-dialog-via-jquery-get)

This works fine when the server is running locally and the save-as dialog appears when the browser is on the same machine as the server. But when the server is running remotely, my browser does not show the dialog when the button is pressed. There are no issues being reported by the server; a GET request is successfully received by the server for the static file. Using Chrome debugger shows that the button press is acknowledged and the callback code is executed without errors (or effect). I've observed this behavior with both Chrome and Firefox.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening?

Comment: Yea I can't blame it. I don't really like anything outside my localhost either ... :P

Comment: Do you have the specific error you get?

Comment: Is the remote server returning the file as an attachment instead of an ordinary document? The Save As dialog is triggered by the server sending "Content-Disposition: Attachment" header.

Comment: <a href="static/staticfile.txt" download='myfile.txt'>download</a>

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: no error, just no behavior at all, but the button click is being triggered.

Comment: @Barmar: it's just a resource file, there's no HTML being returned by the GET, so how would that work? Also, it works locally...

Comment: @dandavis: from Javascript, though?

Comment: @RTF you can call click() or worst-case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent on the link shown. you can then kill the link. see http://danml.com/js/download.js for a script that does just that, plus an extra IE10 routine...

Comment: It has nothing to do with HTML, headers are part of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: @dandavis: thanks, i'm a bit wary of that approach though, having to inject a link into the page temporarily and also the special case handling too. It seems like a bit of a hack. I'd like to take a look at the Content-Disposition before I do the induced link (I can't actually test it out at the minute, unfortunately)

Comment: @Barmar: is it possible for the server to add the 'Content-Disposition' into the header in response to a GET for a particular file? (i'm using mod_wsgi with Django)

Comment: Probably some way with .htaccesss, but I'm not very familiar with that stuff.

Comment: @rtf: i'd rather inject a temporary link than a hidden iframe, if only to prevent re-downloads on a back button click...