# Trigger 'Save As' in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<a>` tag that points to a file on my server:

```
<a href="/files/archive.zip" target="_blank">Download Zip</a>
```

If the user clicks this link, the file will be downloaded immediately. If they right click and click *Save link as...*, they will be prompted for a location to save the file.

Is there any way for me to prompt the user for the location to save the file when they click the link? Or any JavaScript that I could use on a HTML submit element for that matter?

```
<button id="download-zip">Download Zip</button>
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is down to their browser settings, and only bypassable with something like Java, but hopefully someone can clarify

Comment: This is probably a browser setting.

Comment: you are delving into security issues that you wouldn't want anonymous access to and therefore can't access with JS

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Java in a browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing "Save As" dialog via jQuery GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699461/forcing-save-as-dialog-via-jquery-get)

Comment: For modern browsers you can use the [JS FileAPI](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6699599/1045794

Comment: @Barmar Yes, quite common actually.. (used to be, anyway)? I'm referring to Java applets, i.e. the use of a Java counterpart, not a fully Java website

Comment: Lots of people have Java disabled these days, it's rarely used outside some special applications (e.g. Siebel).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is a feature of the user's browser.

- If a default download location is set within the browser the user will not be prompted to select a download location.
- If no default download location is set or the user selected a custom download process (save as) then the browser will present the user with a dialog to select the location for download.